# How to add border to table in html?

Tags: html, css

I know we can add tables with borders in HTML, but there is a sort of error. I tried many times to solve this error but I can't.

Here is my code:

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name
            <th>Courses
            <th>Marks
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Suresh
            <td>Btech
            <td>89
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mukesh
            <td>MBA
            <td>75
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kamlesh
            <td>BA
            <td>90
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's not working? Could you clarify your problem, please?

Comment: you can add border attribute to the table tag

Answer (score 1):

Please change tables to table and add [border="1"] inside the table tag.

Answer (score 1):

The error is given by the plus "s" after the `table`.

Try something like this:

```
    <style>
    td, th, table{
        border: solid 1px;
        }
    <style>
    <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Courses</th>
                    <th>Marks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <br/>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suresh</td>
                    <td>Btech</td>
                    <td>89</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mukesh</td>
                    <td>MBA</td>
                    <td>75</td>
                </tr>
                <br/>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kamlesh</td>
                    <td>BA</td>
                    <td>90</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here it is in action:

```css
td, th, table{
border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Courses</th>
            <th>Marks</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <br/>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Suresh</td>
            <td>Btech</td>
            <td>89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mukesh</td>
            <td>MBA</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>
            <td>Kamlesh</td>
            <td>BA</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```